# How can I execute commands in parallel in a windbg script?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, windbg

I have a windbg script written in JavaScript that gets all the method tables from a memory dump. How can I issue the ExecuteCommand asynchronously so they occur in parallel? The current for loop takes two hours! (We have a huge huge app)

I tried promises but it doesn't support them. I tried yield but it seems to still take two hours as if the ExecuteCommand is blocking. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it's not possible directly.

However, you could try a divide and conquer approach and open *x* dumps at the same time, run *1/x*<sup>th</sup> of the commands on each dump and aggregate the results.

This should be feasible if you have a chance of splitting the commands.

Examples:

- instead of `x *!*` you could run the command `x *!a*`, `x *!b*` etc. on 26 dumps in parallel.
- instead of `!for_each_thread "command"` you could run `command` on as many dumps as there are threads in the dump.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, much of the debug engine is inherently single threaded.  There isn't a way to execute multiple commands in parallel.  The ExecuteCommand bridge does, by definition, "block" until completion of the command as it will capture all debugger output during execution of that command and return it back to the caller as an array of strings.